# Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device Xcode 11

Tags: ios13, xcode11

Just after switching from Xcode 10 to 11, I am unable to install my app on any device

The error at launch time after installation succeeded says : 
Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device.

Details says :

Could not locate installed application
Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
Code: -1
Recovery Suggestion: Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device. bundleId = myBundleId

--
Installed application was not present in database of installed apps after multiple lookup attempts.
Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos

### Code: -1

However everything works fine on a simulator.
I tried to delete derived data, clean project, delete the app ..

Very strange : After submitting the app to testlfight I can download it and it works.
But when I build a new app to Xcode it launch the app just downloaded from tesflight and not the version pushed via Xcode ..

Comment: I have this issue too, I even tried deleting ~/Library/Developer, reinstalling Xcode beta 7, and switching macs. The device console shows there is an error, but the <private> information is not very useful. Best entry I got so far would be Process: streaming_zip_conduit Message: Failed to install application at <private> : Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=35 UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=<private>, FunctionName=<private>, SourceFileLine=38, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}. So sad that I don't know what Code=35 actually means.

Comment: Did you try to submit a bug report at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com?

Comment: Yes I do !
As a workaround, I am using Xcode 10. For those who need to launch an app on iOS 13 device with Xcode 10. Just add 13.1 folder at this path : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport . You can find the 13.0 folder here : https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.0.zip. Just rename it to 13.1, it will work!

Answer (score 2):

### For me, it's a problem with `ipatool`.

Here's a way to find out details why it failed to create a proper iPhone App (.ipa) file from the build output/Xcode archive:

Go to `Product > Archive`, then open `Window > Organizer > Distribute App`.
It should show you "IPA processing failed" with a big red error symbol.
Now, open the logs and search along these lines:

> *timestamp* Assertion failed: Expected *n* archs in otool output:

and

> *timestamp* */Path/to/* Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool exited with 1

While this can't be the final solution, try removing all problematic libraries mentioned in the logs between the two lines until ipatool exists successfully.

Comment: For me, Alamofire v4.9.0 and AppCenter v2.3.0 frameworks were on the list if that helps.

Comment: Alamofire was for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue/error message. I realized that I had automatic signing deactivated and I had selected a provisioning profil with a **distribution** certificate.

**Solution:**
So if you want to run the app on your iphone directly from Xcode (not through testflight) you have to make sure you use a provisioning profil with a **developer** certificate.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the case for most people facing this issue, but I faced it once several days ago and easily dealt with it by cleaning the build folder and switching to a legacy build. The second time I faced it, none of the suggested solutions seemed to be working.

I then noticed that because I'd almost run out of storage on my device, iOS had "offloaded" almost all of my apps. If there is a small cloud under your apps and the app needs to "install" again before launching, then this is the case with your phone too. Trying to launch all of the apps that I don't use regularly (so I never noticed the little clouds) "reinstalled" all of them and solved the issue entirely. Maybe this helps someone facing this for similar reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this alert. That's because i run the app in `release` Build Configuration, but with a `appstore` Provisioning Profile . It's not allowed. So i change the `appstore` Provisioning Profile to a `dev` Profile. Then everything is ok.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem. After I upgraded iOS 13.1, the real machine also ran. Later, I found out that because I had archive operation the day before, the real machine running certificate changed from distribution mode to development mode and everything worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem,I modify the project setting

> File --> Workspace Setting --> Build System --> Legacy Build System

it's OK for me

Answer (score 0):

For my case (xcode 11, ios 12.4), change the **Bundle identifier** can solve this issue...
Before changing Bundle id, I've tried

- using beta xcode
- deleting app on iphone
- deleting derived data
- cleaning project
- reopen xcode

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution. I had previously installed three other apps using XCode and got this error message when I tried to install a fourth.

I simply deleted one of my three existing apps (after hours of hair pulling and SO searching) and tried again. It worked.

Platform: iPad 2018 on v13.1 with XCode v11.1,

Answer (score 0):

I was using different signing team/certificate for ...Tests target. 
Setting the same for main target helped.

Answer (score -1):

Update pods if you have.

```
pod update
```

just it.